# Recursive fetch returns an array of promises instead of values

Tags: javascript, fetch, es6-promise

I'm trying to create a tree of categories from API that returns children of the parent by id.

API example:

```
[
  {
    "attr": {
      "id": "cat_11597"
    },
    "data": "name 1",
    "state": ""
  },
  {
    "attr": {
      "id": "cat_8"
    },
    "data": "name 2",
    "state": "closed"
  }
]

genTree('').then(value => console.log(value));

function genTree(id) {
    return Promise.all([fetch(URL+'getCategories?id=' + id)
        .then(function (response) {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then((treeStructure) => {
            let promises =   treeStructure.map(item  => {
                if (item.state === "closed") {
                    item.children =  getTree(item.attr.id.split('cat_')[1]);
                    return item;
                } else return item;
            });
            return Promise.all(promises);
        })])
};
```

The problem is that console instantly outputs an array of parents and each parents children contain promise instead of an array of children.

Can you tell how I can prevent this so it only returns the whole array without promises?

Thank you.

Comment: `getTree(item.attr.id.split('cat_')[1]);` do you mean `genTree` here? In that case try to wrap the result in `Promise.all` to avoid nesting promises.

Comment: Are you able to use async/await? The easiest solution is to make your `map` callback async like `async item =>` and then use `await` on this line: `item.children = await genTree( ...`

Comment: Another solution is to use `return genTree(item.attr.id.split('cat_')[1]).then( children => { item.children = children; return item; } );` in your if statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> each parents children contain promise instead of an array of children.

Yes, that's what you're doing here:

```
item.children =  getTree(item.attr.id.split('cat_')[1]);
```

The `promises` array doesn't actually contain promises but items, so the `Promise.all` is futile. You need to actually wait for the `getTree` call before assigning its result to the item:

```
function genTree(id) {
    return fetch(URL+'getCategories?id=' + id).then(response => {
        return response.json();
    }).then(treeStructure => {
        let promises = treeStructure.map(item => {
            if (item.state === "closed") {
                return getTree(item.attr.id.split('cat_')[1]).then(children => {
//              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                ^^^^
                    item.children = children;
                    return item;
                })
            } else {
                return Promise.resolve(item);
            }
        });
        return Promise.all(promises);
    });
}
```